# Ajax wipes value of session variable

Tags: ajax, wordpress

I recently added an Ajax-powered load more button that loads additional blog posts to my wordpress site. I used the tutorial listed here: https://rudrastyh.com/wordpress/load-more-posts-ajax.html, and it works, but I've ran into another problem.

I have a session variable that counts the current post number. I show 10 posts per page and the counter works for the initial 10. Then I call the next 10 with ajax and instead of counting to 11, 12, 13 etc, it goes back to 1. There's clearly a problem with passing the end value (10) from the template, to the ajax handler in functions. Anyone know what could be wrong? Everything works if I don't use ajax - it's really frustrating.

**Template PHP**

```
<?php $_SESSION['the_counter'] = 0; ?>
    <?php
    $paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;  
        $args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => 10,
        'paged' => $paged
        );
    $my_query = new WP_Query($args);

    if($my_query->have_posts()):  while($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();
            get_template_part( 'template-parts/post/content', get_post_format() );
        endwhile;
    else:
        get_template_part( 'no-results', 'home' );

endif;
    if ( $my_query->max_num_pages > 1 ){
echo '</a><div class="misha_loadmore">More posts</div>';
}?> 
</div>
<script>var posts_myajax = '<?php echo json_encode( $my_query->query_vars ) ?>',
 current_page_myajax = 1,
 max_page_myajax = <?php echo $my_query->max_num_pages ?>       
</script>

<script src="/loadmore.js"></script>

<?php  $my_query = null;
wp_reset_postdata();?>
```

**Ajax Handler in functions.php**

```
function misha_loadmore_ajax_handler(){


$args = json_decode( stripslashes( $_POST['query'] ), true );
$args['paged'] = $_POST['page'] + 1; // we need next page to be loaded
$args['post_status'] = 'publish';


query_posts( $args );

if( have_posts() ) :

    // run the loop
    while( have_posts() ): the_post();

        // look into your theme code how the posts are inserted, but you can use your own HTML of course
        // do you remember? - my example is adapted for Twenty Seventeen theme
        get_template_part( 'template-parts/post/content', get_post_format() );
        // for the test purposes comment the line above and uncomment the below one
        // the_title();


    endwhile;

endif;
die; }

add_action('wp_ajax_loadmore', 'misha_loadmore_ajax_handler'); 
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_loadmore', 'misha_loadmore_ajax_handler');
```

**Load More JS**

```
jQuery(function($){
$('.misha_loadmore').click(function(){

    var button = $(this),
        data = {
        'action': 'loadmore',
        'query': misha_loadmore_params.posts, // that's how we get params from wp_localize_script() function
        'page' : misha_loadmore_params.current_page
    };

    $.ajax({
        url : misha_loadmore_params.ajaxurl, // AJAX handler
        data : data,
        type : 'POST',
        beforeSend : function ( xhr ) {
            button.text('Loading...'); // change the button text, you can also add a preloader image
        },
        success : function( data ){
            if( data ) { 
                button.text( 'More posts' ).prev().before(data); // insert new posts
                misha_loadmore_params.current_page++;

                if ( misha_loadmore_params.current_page == misha_loadmore_params.max_page ) 
                    button.remove(); // if last page, remove the button

                // you can also fire the "post-load" event here if you use a plugin that requires it
                // $( document.body ).trigger( 'post-load' );
            } else {
                button.remove(); // if no data, remove the button as well
            }
        }
    });
});});
```

And this is the session code I have on the top of my blog post content template file. It increments the count by 1 for every post.

`$counter = $_SESSION['the_counter'];
$counter++;
$_SESSION['the_counter'] = $counter;`

At the bottom of the file, I include:

```
echo insert_counter($the_counter);
```

Comment: provide the full code you used in the question instead of providing some links

Comment: just added the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a glance, I'm betting sessions aren't being set. Try adding this to your functions.php file.

```
 add_action('init', function() {
if (!session_id()) {
    session_start();
});
```

This will ensure that sessions are loading on every page. It's worth mentioning that sessions aren't the best way to persist data. I would recommend replacing the session with a cookie.

Comment: Thanks, but I should have said I set the sessions already. It's still not working :( The funny thing is the counter still updates all the way to ten, so incrementing the session is fine. It's just saving it in the template file and retrieving its current value in the ajax call that's the problem.

Comment: Hmm, ok. Is there any chance that session variable is being overwritten at any point? Try adding <?php error_log(var_export($_SESSION['counter'], true); ?> anywhere your session variable is used and check your error log. You could also try logging the session_id() in your template and ajax call to confirm that the same session is used.

Comment: Thanks mate. I'll give it a go and see how I get on.

Comment: Got it working. You were right, it was being overwritten at the top of my PHP page. 

I had the session variable counter reset to 0 at the start of the page. It was outside the loop, but for some reason, every time the Ajax was called, it ran it anyway? Weird. Anyway I removed it which caused the counter to keep on going up and up. So I added pagination, and set it to equal 0 if it was on page 1. Job done! Thanks for you help mate!